# How to get `Item Index` to functions in v-list-item-action in the Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to get the item index as a param to the function in the `v-list-item-action`. But how? Thanks!

```html
<v-list-item
  v-for="(layer, i) in layers"
  :key="i">
<template v-slot="{ item, index }">
<v-list-item-action>
  <v-btn 
    @click="changeVisible(index)"
    icon>
    <v-icon
      color="blue darken-2"
      v-if="layer.show">
      mdi-eye
    </v-icon>
    <v-icon
      v-else>
      mdi-eye-off
    </v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-list-item-action>
<v-list-item-title v-text="layer.name"></v-list-item-title>
<v-list-item-action>
  <v-btn
    @click="changeEdit" 
    icon>
      <v-icon
      color="blue darken-2"
      v-if="layer.edit">
      mdi-pencil
    </v-icon>
    <v-icon
      v-else>
      mdi-pencil
    </v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-list-item-action>
</template>
</v-list-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't define a template to provide slot content, just add the `index` in `v-for` loop and use it as method parameter :

```
<v-list-item
  v-for="(layer, i) in layers"
  :key="i">
  <v-list-item-action>
   <v-btn 
     @click="changeVisible(i)"
     icon>
     <v-icon
       color="blue darken-2"
      v-if="layer.show">
      mdi-eye
    </v-icon>
    <v-icon
      v-else>
      mdi-eye-off
    </v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-list-item-action>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try to use event-listener to the "v-list-item-action".
document.getElementById("v-list-item-action").addEventListener(event, function);